# URL validation without http:// or https:// in the URL

Tags: templating, url, conditional, plugin-sproutforms

Is is possible to use Craft's URL validation without `http://` or `https://` in the URL?
Or use some sort of function / filter to conditionally add it to the URL if it is missing?

I'm posting a form using sprout forms. The form contains a field that is set to validate as url.
If you post this field without adding `http://` or `https://` it doesn't validate.
Is it possible to somehow to set the [`defaultScheme`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlValidator#defaultScheme-detail) of an url field to http without changing the core Craft UrlValidator or Yii's CUrlValidator?

Comment: Do I get this right, you have a string like `example.com` that represents a URL but is without the `http://` part?

Comment: I'm posting a form which has a website field. In sprout forms i've defined the validation of that form field to be url. However when i post the form, it requires the url to have http:// or https:// in it.

I want users to be able to post example.com and either have it validated as being an url or automaticly have http:// prepended to it

Answer (score 3):

To conditionally add `http://` to strings that don't begin with `http://` or `https://`, use the Twig [matches operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) in a comparison.

To keep the syntax compact, I use a [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) within the `set` tag.

```
{# Set an example URL without `http://` #}
{% set url = 'example.com' %}

{# "Correct" the URL notation #}
{% set url = url matches '/^(https?:\\/\\/)/' ? url : 'http://' ~ url %}

{# Test output #}
{{ url }}
```

.

This is no full URL check in my regular expression, but you could simply work that in too. Pay attention to the escaping character `\` that ([currently](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/pull/1457)) needs to be escaped itself, so you end up with `\\` (it's wrong in the [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunatly it's not the answer i'm looking for. The input of a formfield should be changed on post, not on pageload.  Normally the [defaultSheme](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlValidator#defaultScheme-detail) should automaticly prepend it, but for some reason this isn't working